# innerHTML stripping dynamically added characters

Tags: javascript, html, forms, innerhtml

I'm building a form that displays a preview and I'm having issues with innerHTML stripping dynamic content from a text input field.

The dynamic content is coming from the Inputmask-multi Jquery plugin, which forces phone number formatting. See an example here: http://andr-04.github.io/inputmask-multi/en.html

Firefox and Chrome are stripping the proper formatting and just display the numbers entered by the user.

Form input code:

```
            <label for="wphone_input" id="wphone">Work Phone:<span style="color: #ff0000">*</span><br>
        <input type="text" name="wphone_input" id="wphone_input">
    </label>
```

I'm grabbing the value of the input like this:

```
wphone = frm.wphone_input.value;
```

Then I'm setting the display like this:

```
document.getElementById("wphone2").innerHTML = wphone;
```

Can someone tell me how I might display the input value with proper formatting included?

Comment: to avoid introducing dependencies and custom logic writing which will make your project look more complex, I would put two fields one for area code and one for phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on Chrome. I went to the URL you listed, typed a bunch of 5s in the box, and opened a console window (Note, the input is highlighted so $0 is the input box):

```
$($0).val(); // 55555555555
$($0).data().inputmask.autoUnmask = false; 
$($0).val(); // +555-55-55-5555;
```

So there is probably an `autoUnmask` option you set when initializing the input mask.

Comment: Thank you. I spent far too long on that one.